# How to get the elastic stack-docker running on a laptop?

Tags: docker, elastic

https://github.com/elastic/stack-docker

Running `docker-compose -f setup.yml up` resulted in:

```
Creating network "stack-docker_default" with the default driver
Pulling setup (docker/compose:1.21.2)...
1.21.2: Pulling from docker/compose
605ce1bd3f31: Pull complete
c57f5dd9da06: Pull complete
4869756a2c04: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:6fb081a4ff825a3b9311aa532589bf98b3e9d3331e4f9de69fac31770c8cb108
Status: Downloaded newer image for docker/compose:1.21.2
Creating stack-docker_setup_1 ... done
Attaching to stack-docker_setup_1
setup_1  | Found orphan containers (stack-docker_setup_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
Recreating setup_elasticsearch ... done
Attaching to setup_elasticsearch
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | Determining if x-pack is installed...
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | === CREATE Keystore ===
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | Elastic password is: WCqGii/TGf2banI6JsJF4w==
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | Created elasticsearch keystore in /usr/share/elasticsearch/config
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | Setting bootstrap.password...
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | === CREATE SSL CERTS ===
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | Remove old ca zip...
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | Creating docker-cluster-ca.zip...
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | CA directory exists, removing...
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | Unzip ca files...
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | Archive:  /config/ssl/docker-cluster-ca.zip
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    |    creating: /config/ssl/ca/
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    |   inflating: /config/ssl/ca/ca.crt   
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    |   inflating: /config/ssl/ca/ca.key   
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | Remove old docker-cluster.zip zip...
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | Create cluster certs zipfile...
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | Unzipping cluster certs zipfile...
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | Archive:  /config/ssl/docker-cluster.zip
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    |    creating: /config/ssl/docker-cluster/elasticsearch/
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    |   inflating: /config/ssl/docker-cluster/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.crt  
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    |   inflating: /config/ssl/docker-cluster/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.key  
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    |    creating: /config/ssl/docker-cluster/kibana/
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    |   inflating: /config/ssl/docker-cluster/kibana/kibana.crt  
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    |   inflating: /config/ssl/docker-cluster/kibana/kibana.key  
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    |    creating: /config/ssl/docker-cluster/logstash/
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    |   inflating: /config/ssl/docker-cluster/logstash/logstash.crt  
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    |   inflating: /config/ssl/docker-cluster/logstash/logstash.key  
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | Move logstash certs to logstash config dir...
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | Move kibana certs to kibana config dir...
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch    | Move elasticsearch certs to elasticsearch config dir...
setup_1  | setup_elasticsearch exited with code 0
setup_1  | Found orphan containers (stack-docker_setup_1) for this project. If you removed or renamed this service in your compose file, you can run this command with the --remove-orphans flag to clean it up.
setup_1  | Pulling setup_kibana (docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.0)...
setup_1  | 6.6.0: Pulling from kibana/kibana
setup_1  | Digest: sha256:7c6eadb13667e36d21b7e96809a02d14527c15bbfc5b92631168a58ed5f9fd33
setup_1  | Status: Downloaded newer image for docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.0
setup_1  | Pulling setup_logstash (docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.6.0)...
setup_1  | 6.6.0: Pulling from logstash/logstash
setup_1  | Digest: sha256:5fd22fa584ae6bd9b9e2d23014f23b415ccf8c66cba35cbacb68999f7ee4e2f5
setup_1  | Status: Downloaded newer image for docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:6.6.0
Recreating elasticsearch ... done
Creating setup_logstash  ... done
Creating setup_kibana    ... done
Attaching to setup_logstash, setup_kibana
setup_1  | setup_logstash         | -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 1200 Dec  3 15:35 /usr/share/logstash/config/ca/ca.crt
setup_1  | setup_kibana           | -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 1200 Dec  3 15:35 /usr/share/kibana/config/ca/ca.crt
```

and navigating to http://localhost:5601/ does not return anything.

When `docker-compose up` is run then it fails:

```
Creating logstash        ... error
Creating kibana          ... 

ERROR: for logstash  Cannot create container for service logstash: invalid mount config for type "binCreating kibana          ... error

ERROR: for kibana  Cannot create container for service kibana: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /home/ben/dev/stack-docker/config/kibana/kibana.keystore

ERROR: for logstash  Cannot create container for service logstash: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /home/ben/dev/stack-docker/config/logstash/logstash.keystore

ERROR: for kibana  Cannot create container for service kibana: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /home/ben/dev/stack-docker/config/kibana/kibana.keystore
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic was not able to start. The logging indicated:

```
[2019-12-09T10:22:15,124][INFO ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [kViKuCL] bound
or publishing to a non-loopback address, enforcing bootstrap checks
ERROR: [1] bootstrap checks failed
[1]: max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low,
increase to at least [262144]
```

The latter is also depicted in the [README.md](https://github.com/elastic/stack-docker):

```
sudo sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=262144
```

Once this was changed and

```
docker-compose -f setup.yml up --remove-orphans
```

[was run](https://github.com/elastic/stack-docker/issues/73#issuecomment-476068864), the logging continued:

```
setup_1  | setup_packetbeat       | Loading dashboards (Kibana must be running and reachable)
setup_1  | setup_heartbeat        | Loaded dashboards
setup_1  | setup_heartbeat        | Copy keystore to ./config dir
setup_1  | setup_heartbeat exited with code 0
setup_1  | setup_auditbeat        | Loaded dashboards
setup_1  | setup_auditbeat        | Copy keystore to ./config dir
setup_1  | setup_auditbeat exited with code 0
setup_1  | setup_packetbeat       | Loaded dashboards
setup_1  | setup_packetbeat       | Copy keystore to ./config dir
setup_1  | setup_packetbeat exited with code 0
setup_1  | setup_metricbeat       | Loaded dashboards
setup_1  | setup_metricbeat       | Copy keystore to ./config dir
setup_1  | setup_metricbeat exited with code 0
setup_1  | setup_filebeat         | Loaded dashboards
setup_1  | setup_filebeat         | Loaded machine learning job configurations
setup_1  | setup_filebeat         | Copy keystore to ./config dir
setup_1  | setup_filebeat exited with code 0
setup_1  | Setup completed successfully. To start the stack please run:
setup_1  |   docker-compose up -d
setup_1  | 
setup_1  | If you wish to remove the setup containers please run:
setup_1  |  docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.setup.yml down --remove-orphans
setup_1  | 
setup_1  | You will have to re-start the stack after removing setup containers.
setup_1  | 
setup_1  | Your 'elastic' user password is: mnQ9c5FCGT09sRgHPnw27A==
stack-docker_setup_1 exited with code 0
```

Subsequently, running `docker-compose up -d`, resulted in:

```
Recreating elasticsearch ... done
Recreating kibana        ... done
Creating logstash        ... done
Creating apm_server      ... done
Creating packetbeat      ... done
Creating metricbeat      ... done
Creating filebeat        ... done
Creating heartbeat       ... done
Creating auditbeat       ... done
```

Navigating to http://localhost:5601 returns the kibana UI.

[image]